# Using doseq and atoms rather than loop/recur

Tags: clojure

I have been rewriting Land Of Lisp's orc-battle game in Clojure. During the process I am using a more functional style. I have come up with two methods for writing part of the higher level game loop. One involving loop/recur and the other using doseq and atoms. Here are the two functions:

```
(defn monster-round [player monsters]
  (loop [n 0 p player]
    (if (>= n (count monsters))
      p
      (recur (inc n)
         (if (monster-dead? (nth monsters n))
           p
           (let [r (monster-attack (nth monsters n) p)]
             (print (:attack r))
             (:player r)))))))


(defn monster-round-2 [player monsters]
  (let [p (atom player)]
    (doseq [m monsters]
      (if (not (monster-dead? m))
        (let [r (monster-attack m @p)]
             (print (:attack r))
             (reset! p (:player r)))))
    @p))
```

I like the second method better because the code is more concise and is easier to follow. Is there any reason why the first approach is better? Or am I missing a different way to do this?

Comment: As suggested in @andrew answer, in FP you should first try to model the computation/processing using standard higher order functions like reduce, map etc and If that doesn't fit your need then you should your  more primitives like recur/loops etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is this equivalent?  if so, i prefer it - it's compact, clearer than your solutions (imho!),  and functional

```
(defn monster-round [monsters player]
  (if-let [[monster & monsters] monsters]
    (recur monsters
      (if (monster-dead? monster)
        player
        (let [r (monster-attack monster player)]
          (print (:attack r))
          (:player r))))
    player))
```

(note: i changed the argument order to `monster-round` so that the recur looked nicer)

more generally, you should not have introduced `n` in your "functional" version (it's not really really functional if you've got an index...).  indexing into a sequence is very, very rarely needed.  if you had fought the temptation to do that a little harder, i think you would have written the routine above...

but, after writing that, i thought: "hmmm. that's just iterating over monsters.  why can't we use a standard form?  it's not a for loop because player changes.  so it must be a fold (ie a reduce), which carries the player forwards".  and then it was easy to write:

```
(defn- fight [player monster]
  (if (monster-dead? monster)
    player
    (let [r (monster-attack monster player)]
      (print (:attack r))
      (:player r))))

(defn monster-round [player monsters]
  (reduce fight player monsters))
```

which (if it does what you want) is the Correct Answer(tm).

(maybe i am not answering the question?  i think you missed the better way, as above.  in general, you should be able to thread the computation around the data structure, which does normally not require mutation; often you can - and should - use the standard forms like map and reduce because they help document the process for others).

Comment: Fantastic, I like the reduce approach. I didn't like my first approach because I was not processing the data structure. Hadn't even thought of using reduce.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the private function fight as opposed to declaring the function with-in monster-round using letfn?

Comment: i am not sure.  in theory the compiler should be able to lift the function out (so that it's not rebuilt on every call to monster-round) because it would not capture any variables, and i guess it will do so.  so i guess letfn is better really, because it bundles things together.  i don't use it much because i find it ugly/hard to read, but that's probably just me.

Comment: I just redid a similar function using letfn, it was ugly and harder to read, so I removed the letfn. So you are not the only one who thinks it is uglier.